# I need to create a database structure where there could be variable parameter values, what's the best way to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I need to create a database (SQL Server) where you can have items that can have several parameter values, but not all are required. Basically what I need is to store items, that have a type. Each type has parameters that can be filled in. For those parameters a value needs to be stored as well. And it needs to be performant enough!

So for example:

RowId - Item ID - Name - TypeOfItem - Price - DateOfSale - Var1 - Var2 - Var3 - ...(but then 10 more parameters and they could be dinamically added! And they're different based on the "TypeOfItem" field!)

In this case how can I best implement it?

So for option 1 I thought about the following:

1. I could implement it like this:

RowId - 1 - Fridge - Price - int (type of field) - 3000 .

"1" being the ID, "Fridge" being the TypeOfItem name, "Price" being the parameter name, "int" being the parameter type and "3000" being the value.

Then another line could be added for item with ID "1", that's also a fridge, but then maybe "Name" as parameter, "string" as type and "Fridgety" as name as value or something.

2. I could also do it like this:

RowId - ItemID - Type - (list of all parameters, even the ones this type doesn't need)

This would mean that a lot of parameter columns will be "NULL" because the selected type "Fridge" for example doesn't have some parameter that "Computer" does have. And then for Computer some other columns would default to "NULL" etc...

This also doesn't seem optimal because you'd have a hughe table, filled with loads of "NULL" values of parameters that aren't needed for the item's type.

3. Per type, store the items in the DB. So I'd have a table "items" that stores their ID, name and possible other common (across all types) of parameters. Then I could have a table for all "Fridges", for all "Radios" etc. that are linked to the ItemID. Then table fridge can have it's 10 params that are needed, radio can have their 7, etc.

What this means however is a lot of joining and has a performance impact. Also it's harder to add a "random amount of variable parameters" because that would mean we'd have to add columns dynamically etc...

To recap: I'm looking to structure my data decent and my data needs to store items, types of items, different parameters based on the item type, and then the values for those parameters.

Personally, I think option 1 could be the best? Yes it has a lot of useless columns that are filled to the brim with "NULL" values as only 1 column per "parameter key" will be filled in. But performance wise it will be best since you only read from 1 table (correct?). Also it's easier to dynamically add parameters, for example if some user wants to add a new parameter "comments", it's just another record in that table.

Back-end modelwise, I can handle the "dynamically added parameters" in a key-value array or list or something. Then for each of those items, I write a record to the DB (in option 1)

Does anyone have experience with something like this and can help me out to choose the best way? Thanks!

Comment: KVP? Not my favorite.

Comment: You shoulld name the columns to be representative of what they hold, not `var1`, `var2`, `var`, etc. Just because you have different types of items doesn't mean that they can't go in the same column, just some columns would have a `NULL` value.

Comment: @Tempuslight you could always store your properties as a `json` string under one column in your table. WHen you query the table, deserialize the properties for that object.

Comment: Or, if you're using an older version of SQL Server, XML is also acceptable instead of JSON.

Comment: Look up [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Handle the performance part in a later stage, joins are not evil...

Comment: @RyanWilson ah yes that was another option I had but forgot to write down, sorry, my head's kind of full... So I could store the JSON (or XML) in a string typed column called "Parameters", in the items table? 

Will it be easy to query these parameters? Like, give me all fridges between price of 2000 and 3000? Can SQL deserialize during querying (from .NET Core/ LINQ)? And is that performant? 

it would be on an Azure SQL (cloud)

Comment: @Tempuslight `Price` seems like a common column to all items, I would store `Price` as it's own column and store the properties that can be different based on the item type as the `json` or `xml`. Especially if you want to filter your table based on `Price`, you could also add an index to that column as well for faster look up.

Comment: @Sander I think I tried that one as well, I tried doing it like this: 

RowId - ID - TypeID - DataType - ParameterKey - Value

1 - 1 - 74 (to Fridge) - int - Price - 3000
2 - 1 - 74 - string - Name - MyBestFridge
3 - 1 - 74 - dateTime - DateOfPurchase - 09/09/2020

Etc... Is this how you mean? However, then that last "value" column, would have to be string (to be able to store all data types), but then querying this would be harder, for example "give me all fridges of the past 3 months".

Comment: @RyanWilson True, indexing those more common columns will be more performant and cleaner in our DB. However, say a fridge needs "watt" and a computer needs "CPU" or something. This could be stored in the JSON yes. But what If the user wants all fridges with X watt? How easy is it to index or query those values in the JSON?

Comment: @Tempuslight This fellow wrote up a nice article on utilizing `json` columns and performance times and enhancements - (https://blogit.create.pt/goncalomelo/2018/12/20/query-performance-for-json-objects-inside-sql-server/)

Comment: @RyanWilson Great, thanks for the amazing help! I think I'll make some different structures locally and see how they work & can be implemented most easily. If this JSON option is performant enough, I think doing it that way is easiest

Comment: @Tempuslight Have a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae7396b49beebd8e33a7270d530dd6d9) that demonstrates my proposed design.

Comment: @RyanWilson I've read the articles on using the JSON parameters table. However in those examples, even with indexes, it always has "phoneNumber". But in our "params" table, with JSON, there will be JSONs with different keys etc, so we can't index them, so a query will take like 10 seconds instead of 13 milliseconds... Is there a fix for that issue? Because we can't have indexes on (potential) param keys that we don't know yet.

Comment: @Sander Nice :o! Thanks for the effort to show me that. It's easier for me to visualize. But won't this also have one GIANT table, with records for each item/each parameter? Also, won't the numerous joins be a performance issue/hit? Is it easy to work with if new types or tables have to be created? 

Also, "PropValue" always has to be a string right? Is it easy to say "give me all fridges sold in the past 3 months"? You'll have to parse all the date strings to DateTimes first, etc... You know what I mean?

Comment: @Tempuslight Multiple joins do not _have_ the be a performance issue if properly indexed. SQL Server does not fear joins, it is a [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), _it was made for it_. Yes, the transactional data tables could potentially get very large, but you have to store it _somewhere_. The normalization avoids duplicate values.

Comment: @Tempuslight Here's an article about using indexes on json properties using non persistent computed columns - (https://hackernoon.com/one-sql-cheat-code-for-blazing-fast-json-queries-d0cb6160d380). According to this, it makes the already speedy built in `json` functions extremely fast. This talks about a built in `json` function of `JSON_VALUE` - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You'd need to do some performance testing yourself to see what suits you best.

Comment: @Tempuslight To answer your last question: no, you will not have to cast the dates. In my proposed design the property type `SaleDate` would be stored in `ItemPropDate` where `PropValue` has data type `date`. In my first example query I used the fridge purchase date as an example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to avoid storing JSON or XML data structures in your database design, here is another design suggestion to get my idea of normalization across.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6632084e2d10899d28b65e6ae9a9c0ab) to see all the things below in action.

**Table design**

This design is incomplete! See future actions near the bottom.

```
-- item configuration data

create table ItemType -- define item types
(
  TypeId int,
  TypeName nvarchar(100)
);
create table PropType -- define property types
(
  PropId int,
  PropName nvarchar(100)
);
create table ItemTypeProp -- link property types to item types
(
  TypeId int,
  PropId int
);

-- transactional item data

create table Item -- links item to type
(
  ItemId int,
  ItemName nvarchar(100),
  TypeId int
);
create table ItemPropString -- item string property values
(
  ItemId int,
  PropId int,
  PropValue nvarchar(100) --string...
);
create table ItemPropInt -- item integer property values
(
  ItemId int,
  PropId int,
  PropValue int --integer...
);
create table ItemPropDate -- item date property values
(
  ItemId int,
  PropId int,
  PropValue date --date...
);
```

**Sample configuration data**

```
-- independent item types
insert into ItemType (TypeId, TypeName) values
(1, 'Fridge'),
(2, 'Moon');

-- independent property types
insert into PropType (PropId, PropName) values
(1, 'Height'),
(2, 'Width'),
(3, 'PurchaseDate'),
(4, 'Color');

-- assign properties to items (NO, you cannot purchase the items of type Moon)
insert into ItemTypeProp (TypeId, PropId) values
(1, 1), -- Fridge > Height
(1, 2), -- Fridge > Width
(1, 3), -- Fridge > PurchaseDate
(1, 4), -- Fridge > Color
(2, 2), -- Moon > Width
(2, 4); -- Moon > Color
```

**Sample transactional data**

```
insert into Item (ItemId, ItemName, TypeId) values
(1, 'The Blue Fridge', 1),
(2, 'Your Fridge', 1),
(3, 'Mimas', 2);

insert into ItemPropString (ItemId, PropId, PropValue) values
(1, 4, 'Blue'),
(3, 4, 'Gray');

insert into ItemPropInt (ItemId, PropId, PropValue) values
(1, 1, 200),
(3, 2, 396);

insert into ItemPropDate (ItemId, PropId, PropValue) values
(1, 3, '2020-01-01');
```

**Sample queries**

```
-- all fridges purchased in 2020
select i.ItemId, i.ItemName, it.TypeName, pt.PropName, ipd.PropValue
from Item i
join ItemType it
  on it.TypeId = i.TypeId
join ItemTypeProp itp
  on itp.TypeId = it.TypeId
join PropType pt
  on pt.PropId = itp.PropId
join ItemPropDate ipd
  on  ipd.ItemId = i.ItemId
  and ipd.PropId = pt.PropId
where it.TypeName = 'Fridge'
  and pt.PropName = 'PurchaseDate'
  and year(ipd.PropValue) = 2020;

-- all item types with their possible properties
select it.TypeId, it.TypeName, pt.PropId, pt.PropName
from ItemType it
join ItemTypeProp itp
  on itp.TypeId = it.TypeId
join PropType pt
  on pt.PropId = itp.PropId;

-- The Blue Fridge with all its possible properties and available values
select i.ItemId,
       i.ItemName,
       it.TypeName,
       pt.PropName,
       coalesce(ips.PropValue,
                convert(nvarchar(100), ipi.PropValue),
                convert(nvarchar(100), ipd.PropValue)) as PropValue
from Item i
join ItemType it
  on it.TypeId = i.TypeId
join ItemTypeProp itp
  on itp.TypeId = it.TypeId
join PropType pt
  on pt.PropId = itp.PropId
left join ItemPropString ips
  on  ips.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ips.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join ItemPropInt ipi
  on  ipi.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ipi.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join ItemPropDate ipd
  on  ipd.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ipd.ItemId = i.ItemId
where i.ItemName = 'The Blue Fridge';

-- The Blue Fridge with all its possible properties and available values PIVOTED
with cte as
(
select i.ItemId,
       i.ItemName,
       it.TypeName,
       pt.PropName,
       coalesce(ips.PropValue,
                convert(nvarchar(100), ipi.PropValue),
                convert(nvarchar(100), ipd.PropValue)) as PropValue
from Item i
join ItemType it
  on it.TypeId = i.TypeId
join ItemTypeProp itp
  on itp.TypeId = it.TypeId
join PropType pt
  on pt.PropId = itp.PropId
left join ItemPropString ips
  on  ips.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ips.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join ItemPropInt ipi
  on  ipi.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ipi.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join ItemPropDate ipd
  on  ipd.PropId = pt.PropId
  and ipd.ItemId = i.ItemId
where i.ItemName = 'The Blue Fridge'
)
select p.*
from cte
pivot (max(cte.PropValue) for PropName in ([Height], [Width], [PurchaseDate], [Color])) p
```

**Remarks**

Positives:

- Normalized: no values are saved twice
- Very extendible design, for example: an item type could have a certain property starting from a certain date (add column `ItemTypeProp.FromDate`)
- No need to store all property values as string values (meaning you can use data type specific functions like `year()`)
- No need to deal with JSON or XML functions and path expressions in your queries

Future action points:

- `ItemPropInt` will need a `UnitId` column (Saturn's moon Mimas is 396 *KM* wide vs. The Blue Fridge is 200 *CM* tall)
- Add constrains to avoid adding property values for property types not linked to an item type
- Add indexes on the proper Id and Name fields in order to speed up queries